# Alinhamento bootstrap não está correto

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Tentei fazer um alinhamento com bootstrap, de modo que eu tivesse o label e ao lado dele o controle. Bem, pensando dessa forma, optei pela classe .`form-horizontal`. Bem, quando renderizo o site, o alinhamento fica com o label em cima e o controle em baixo. Pelo código não está certo o resultado. Fiz inúmeras tentativas e não consegui nada. Estou lendo sobre o bootstrap, mas ainda não consegui o resultado esperado.

```
<div id="agendamento">
     <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
         <div class="control-group">
             <label for="txtCnpjOs" class="control-label">CNPJ:</label>
             <div class="controls col-sm-03">
              <input type="text" class="span2" id="txtCnpjOs" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="control-group">
             <label for="txtOS" class="control-label">OS:</label>
             <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="input-small col-sm-03" id="txtOS" placeholder="Digite o numero da OS">
            </div><br />
            <input id="btnPesquisar" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Pesquisar" onclick=" return MontaAgendamento();" />
         </div>

     </form> 
     <br />

     <div id="filtro">
         <div id="FiltroPesquisa">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="txtAcao" id="lblProxAcao" class="control-label">Ação</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="txtAcao" type="text" readonly="true" value="" />
                        <input id="txtProxAcao" type="text" readonly="true" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="txtDataCadastro" class="control-label">Data Cadastro</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="txtDataCadastro" type="text" readonly="true" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <label for="txtIDV99" class="control-label">ID V99:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="txtIDV99" type="text" readonly="true" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
     </div>
 </div> @*Fecho a div agendamento*@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o Bootstrap 2.3.2 ou o 3.2.0?

Pergunto porque se você estiver utilizando o 2.3.2 na documentação não existe o **role="form"** e nem as classes de grid **.col-sm-3**.

Caso esteja usando o 3.2.0 as classes para serem utilizadas nos forms mudaram, segue abaixo um exemplo dos dois para você comparar:

v2.3.2

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

v3.2.0

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Você irá substituir a classe **.control-group** por **.form-control** e adicionar nos inputs a classe **.form-control**.

Verifica bem qual das duas versões do bootstrap está usando e para maiores esclarecimentos abaixo a documentação das duas versões.

v3.2.0 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

v2.3.2 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei ao label um tamanho `col-sm-2` e foi suficiente para alinhar a esquerda do campo.
Na documentação [getbootstrap-forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) tem essas informações.

Comment: A classe de CSS `.col-sm-*` aplica-se a uma resoluçaõ `≥768px` até `<992px`. Não resolve nada no meu ecrã que é bem maior... De qualquer forma, o OP tem as classes de CSS com erros! Onde se lê `col-sm-03` deveria ler-se `col-sm-3`.

Comment: @Zuul eu tenho pouco conhecimento com bootstrap, mas creio que .col-*-* está mais relacionado ao limite mínimo, por tanto se você acessar em um ecrã maior, ainda sim verá o site normal, o que não acontece é se acessar em uma resolução inferior ao `sm`. No código dele eu tinha visto esses erros, o ideal é seguir o bootstrap oficial e não misturar as versões.

Comment: Uso a versão 3.2.0 do bootstrap. Não entendo porque não funciona como gostaria.

Comment: Acho que faltou a class .controls. Consegui fazer funcionar, alterando o código citado.